# How to answer this question?

Tags: questions

This is the question: Did there use to be a different capital city?
So, I don't  know if I have to ask " Yes, it did" or " yes, There was"..I will be so thankful if you can help me! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's common in immediate answers to questions during conversations, especially simple ones, to elide everything after the verb or first word of the verb, because the rest can be assumed from the question.

So you say:

> There was (short for "There was a capital city.").

or:

> There did (short for "There did use to be a capital city."  This is more emphasized than the above).

You wouldn't say *Yes, it did* because the *there* is the subject of the question, not *it*.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that we simply invert the word order to change from a question to a statement or vice-versa.

**Did there** use to be a different capital city?

Yes, **there did** use to be a different capital city.

Yes, **there did**.